# openpyxl Setting Property values like Company and Comments

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to set up an Excel template using openpyxl.

I can set some of the information set in the Properties Summary like Title, Subject and keywords.

But I cant figure out the Company or Comments or Hyperlink.

I believe those are in the "openpyxl.packaging.extended module"?

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.properties import WorksheetProperties, PageSetupProperties
from openpyxl.packaging.extended import ExtendedProperties

wb = Workbook()

wb.properties.title = "my Excel Template"
wb.properties.subject = "Cashflow Template"
wb.properties.keywords = "Version 1.0"
```

I can not get these added.

```
wb.properties.company = "My Company"

wb.properties.comments = "This is the private property of My Company.  Any unauthorized use will be subjected to legal actions."
```

What am I missing here?

Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

wb.save('myfile.xlsx')
You need to save your workbook